# Why wont my email validation work? PHP

Tags: php, validation, email, forms

I have used

```
if (!preg_match('/[a-z||0-9]@[a-z||0-9].[a-z]/', $email)) {
    [PRINT ERROR]
}
```

&

```
if (!eregi( "^[0-9]+$", $email)) {
    [PRINT ERROR]
}
```

&

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    [PRINT ERROR]
}
```

I have also tried taking out the ! and make it work backwards but for some reason NONE of those work to find out if it is valid. Any ideas why?...
I have it in an else if statement, Im not sure if that could be the cause..

I am using PHP

Comment: Maybe you could provide *it*? What is in `$email`?

Comment: $email is from a form. The input field's name is email and I used $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ; to collect the info in it. I know this part is working as I can get the correct info to email to myself

Comment: This worked thank you, I guess when I did mine it was messed up somewhere

Comment: Your first two ifs and regular expressions are totally screwed anyhow. Now `filter_var` does the correct thing, so it's easy to assume the supplied test case was really invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
'/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/'
```

...

```
if (!preg_match('/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/', strtoupper($email))) {
    [PRINT ERROR]
}
```

As far as I can see, none of your regex expressions would match an email.

Comment: I just coped that off of a website, I fixed it up for my email validation when I was trying to make it work, ill try yours and see if that works maybe I just messed up when I did mine

Answer (score 1):

Try this from the Kohana source code:

```
function email($email)
{
    return (bool) preg_match('/^[-_a-z0-9\'+*$^&%=~!?{}]++(?:\.[-_a-z0-9\'+*$^&%=~!?{}]+)*+@(?:(?![-.])[-a-z0-9.]+(?<![-.])\.[a-z]{2,6}|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?::\d++)?$/iD', (string) $email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your php version. [eregi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) is deprecated after 5.3.0. Also, the regex is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (from wordpress):

```
// from wordpress code: wp-includes/formatting.php
function is_email($user_email)
{
    $chars = "/^([a-z0-9+_]|\\-|\\.)+@(([a-z0-9_]|\\-)+\\.)+[a-z]{2,6}\$/i";

    if (strpos($user_email, '@') !== false && strpos($user_email, '.') !== false)
    {
        if (preg_match($chars, $user_email)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```